# Android CoordinatorLayout + AppbarLayout + Viewpager layout exceeds height of screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

when i put viewpager along with  CoordinatorLayout + AppbarLayout + Viewpager ,viewpager exceeds the screen size , please help me to solve.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Preview image of design]

[image: Mobile view]

As you can see, the height of ViewPager is exceeding its parent layout causing some elements below clipped, and I wonder why?

Comment: can u plz run it on device and give screen shot of it

Comment: chk again @vishal patel bro

Answer (score -1):

please remove "app:layout_behavior" and check

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"